# Is there a 2D and 3D data visualization (plotting) plugin for eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, data-visualization

I'm looking for a data visualization plugin that will let me view 2D and 3D charts of vectors and 2D arrays. My search couldn't find something to offer this functionality.

UPDATE: I mean to be able to see my signal processing data before and after applying a filter program, for example. I put in a noisy signal and see a nice sine wave when plotting the output. This is available in Analog Devices' VisualDSP++ IDE, for example, but I am not sure it is available on MS Visual Studio.

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about. Would you like to view datastructures in 2D and 3D while coding/debugging or would you like to visualize 2D and 3D graphs in your software?

Comment: @kandilaki - I want to view graphs of my data (like in "graphics calculator", not like in "graph theroy"). So, if I am writing a FFT program, I want to view the input and output vectors.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning 3D visualization consider [GEF3D](http://eclipse.org/gef3d/) (Graphical Editing Framework 3D) and for 2D visualization simple [GEF](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/). Both are some kind of frameworks for manipulating your data model with a graphical editor. The underlying framework is [draw2d](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/draw2d/index.php) which might be more appropriate for your purpose. You could also look what technology is used in the Eclipse reporting framework [BIRT](http://eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/) (where drawing graphs should be an inherent part).

Comment: Thanks. GEF looks as if it is oriented towards drawing schematics and not graphs, but I'm sure it can be modified for that task as well. As of BIRT - for the link you provided, I am not sure where exactly is the *graphics* module of this report generator that I can take advantage of to generate sci graphs.